# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header Missing

Tags: php, cross-domain, plesk

I have included this javascript on other domains:

```
var id = "<?php echo check_input($_GET['token']); ?>";
    var querystring = "";
    var lockerurl = "https:\/\/www.example.com\/contentlocker\/getlocker.php?" + 'id=' + encodeURIComponent(id) + '&r=' + encodeURIComponent(referrer) + querystring;


    var iframecontents;
    var old_display;

    function optionstoquery(options) {

        var query = "";

        if (options.mt) query += "&mt=" + encodeURIComponent(options.mt);
        if (options.dt) query += "&dt=" + encodeURIComponent(options.dt);
        if (options.dd) query += "&dd=" + encodeURIComponent(options.dd);
        if (options.md) query += "&md=" + encodeURIComponent(options.md);

        return query;

    }

    function og_load(options) {

        if (options) lockerurl += optionstoquery(options);

                        //preload
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', lockerurl, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState!==4) return;
                if (this.status!==200) {
                    iframecontents = false;
                    return;
                }

                iframecontents = this.responseText;
            };
            xhr.send();

            ogEditBody();
                }
```

Console it show me:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://www.example.com/contentlocker/getlocker.php?id=3e066b64a78214a17620b5521b6d3ec4&r=aHR0cDovL2NwYWh1Yi51cy9yb29zdGVyMi5odG1s.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

getlocker.php contains some php and html code!

I using Plesk as webserver and I have tried by adding in getlocker.php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

But still not working!

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` = doing it wrong. [The right way](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9ea48e5f02e4aaea34dc7f7584ee1bb0680e098e/687474703a2f2f7777772e68746d6c35726f636b732e636f6d2f7374617469632f696d616765732f636f72735f7365727665725f666c6f7763686172742e706e67)

Answer (score 0):

The CORS header has to be sent in the main page request so if you just set it when you send an embedded scrip that is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first line in your PHP file?

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Also, try sending `crossDomain: true` in your AJAX call or HTTPRequest.

Comment: Yes, it is first line. How I can add crossDomain: true  ?

Answer (score 0):

From the server side, on Linux server, you can set up the required header in web server configuration:

For source domain `example.com` in Plesk go to `Domains > example.com > Apache and nginx settings` and add the following directives in `Additional directives for HTTP` and `Additional directives for HTTPS`:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Alternatively, in this case, `.htaccess` file with the following content can be used:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>p
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

If Nginx is enabled and static content needed to be displayed, use the following directive in `Additional nginx directives` field without Apache directives:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
```

Comment: I have added `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";`  in `Additional nginx directives` and still show me same error!